# How to record a node's child nodes when building a double-array trie?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, trie

I want to build a double array trie for some key-value data, but I need record each node's child nodes when add a key, it is easy to do that for building a standard trie, but I have no idea about how to do it on a double array trie. Now, I only first build a trie and then build a double array trie according to the trie, but I think is inconvenient. Do you have any good idea to do it? Thank you.

Comment: For those of you who haven't heard of the double-array, the original paper can be found here: http://sc.snu.ac.kr/~xuan/spe777ja.pdf

Comment: I have read the paper, but it doesn't tell how to record one node's child nodes when adding.

Comment: @lixiang- My apologies - I posted that think so that people unfamiliar with the atructure (including me when I first read this!) would know what a double array trie is.  It was not intended as an answer to this question, and I don't fully understand the structure myself!

Answer (score 0):

for english, you don't need to save child's nodes, since it just has 56 characters. when collision occurs, you can simply check every possible character to see if it s a child.